# How to retrieve all transactions from bitcoind?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, json-rpc

I am working on a project that need to parse all transactions from bitcoind. I have been using bitcoind which the option txindex=1 and pulling transactions using RPC call getRawTransaction. It work, but is very slow.

Is there any fast way to pull all transactions from bitcoind? (I dont need to pull them in order).

I tried to read then directly from bitcoind DB, but according to [What is the database for?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/what-is-the-database-for) transactions are not stored in levelDB, there are only at blockXXX.dat, in network format, so I would need to parse the block to extract them, which doesnt seem OK (I guess that orphan blocks are also there, so that will generate problems).

Answer (score 3):

Making an RPC call per transaction adds a lot of overhead.

It's not clear exactly what you mean by 'all transactions', but I'll assume you have a way of identifying 'all blocks' for which you want the transactions.

You can reduce the overhead, then, to one RPC call per block, by using getblock with the second option (verbose) set to false (getblock *blockhash* false), and then parsing the raw block data directly yourself.

There's a bit of work involved in parsing the raw block data yourself, but if you're already working with raw transaction data then I guess you may already have the code to do the relevant decoding.
If not, it's not too hard to set this up, in any case.

As a side effect, note that the full transaction index (txindex=1) is no longer required with this method.

I've written about this specific issue in more detail in [this blog post](http://upcoder.com/8/fast-blockchain-scanning/), so check this post for more details, and some example code..

Comment: I would recommend to get the raw block from bitcoind and then use bitcoinj to parse that block (if using JVM).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to my comment above, below is Scala code to parse the entire bitcoind blockchain and extract raw blocks. It uses Bitcoinj.jar library to further parse the raw block.

The blocks are stored in files `blkxxxxx.dat`. The structure of the file is [as follows](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/65083/2075):

```
4 | 4 | 80 | TxData | 4 | 4 | 80 | TxData | 4 | 4 | 80 | TxData | ...
```

- First 4 bytes: magic bytes (identifying which network you are on)
- Second 4 bytes: the number of bytes of the remaining block
- Next 80 bytes: block header itself
- Next NumBlockBytes - 80 bytes: Transaction data in this block [ numTx | Tx1 | Tx2 | Tx3 | ... ]

In my system, I was able to iterate through all the files (1000+) within 4 hours (no verification or processing of block bytes, just the dummy code below). There was around 140 GB data on the blockchain at that time. Perhaps some Scala gurus can make it faster.

Interestingly, when I was syncing bitcoind for the first time, it finished within 6 hours which includes downloading and verifying the blocks. So this will be faster in C++.

Also you'll have to deal with orphans.

```
import java.io._
import java.nio._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.bitcoinj.core._
import org.bitcoinj.params._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Utils {

  // Used for closing files implicitly
  def using[A <: {def close(): Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B = try { f(param) } finally { param.close() }

  // this is the method that actually parses the file
  def parseFile(name:String) = { 
    System.gc // large files (around 140 MB each, need to clear memory)
    using(new FileInputStream(name)) {fis =>
      using(new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {bis =>
        var currBlkByte = -1 // which byte of raw block are we reading?
        var currBlk = 0 // which block is currently being read?
        var currBlkSize = -1L // what is the size of block (in bytes)
        var endBlkByte = -1 // which is the ending byte of current block?

        val blkSizeBytes = new ArrayBuffer[Byte] // stores bytes containing data about block size
        val blkBytes = new ArrayBuffer[Byte] // stores bytes of block

        Stream.continually(bis.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).foreach{int =>
          currBlkByte += 1  
          val byte = int.toByte 
          // ignore first 4 bytes (magic bytes), next 4 bytes stores upcoming block's size in little endian
          if (currBlkByte >= 4 && currBlkByte < 8) blkSizeBytes += byte
          if (currBlkByte == 7) { // this byte is the last one encoding block's size
            currBlkSize = ByteBuffer.wrap(blkSizeBytes.toArray).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt & 0xFFFFFFFFL;            
            endBlkByte = currBlkSize.toInt + 7 // first 8 bytes for info, remaining encoding block
            blkSizeBytes.clear // clear for next block
          }
          if (currBlkByte > 7) blkBytes += byte  // block data 
          if (currBlkByte == endBlkByte) { // we have reached end of block
            // last block byte
            currBlk += 1 // increment block count
            currBlkByte = -1 // reset
            endBlkByte = -1 // reset
            parseBlk(blkBytes.toArray) // we have block in bytes, lets parse it
            blkBytes.clear // reset
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }

  val context = new Context(MainNetParams.get) // needed for Bitcoinj v 0.13 and above

  def parseBlk(bytes:Array[Byte]) = { // uses Bitcoinj    
    new Block(MainNetParams.get, bytes).getTransactions.foreach {tx =>
      val hash = tx.getHashAsString
      val inputs = tx.getInputs
      val outputs = tx.getOutputs
      // do something with above
    }
  }
  def getAllFiles(dir:String, extensions:Array[String], recursive:Boolean) = 
    FileUtils.listFiles(new File(dir), extensions, recursive).toArray.map(_.toString)

}
import Utils._

object BlockParser {
  val dir = "/home/user/.bitcoin/blocks"
  //files have names like blk00000.dat, ..., blk01096.dat (last one at time of writing)
  val files = getAllFiles(dir, Array("dat"), false).collect {
    case name if name.contains("blk") => // collect only those file with names like "blkxxxxx.dat"
      val num = name.drop(s"$dir/blk".size).take(5).toInt // (take 5 is based on actual file names)
        (name, num)      
  }.sortBy(_._2).unzip._1 // sort by file number 

  files.foreach(parseFile)
}
```