# What is current size of various databases in Bitcoin Core as of July 2014?

Tags: blockchain, database

This question is related to question: [What is the database for?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/what-is-the-database-for/11108#11108)

What is size in MB of:

- blockchain itsef - blocks/blk*.dat
- blocks/index/*
- chainstate/*
- blocks/rev*.dat

Is the size of chainstate and index proportional to blockchain size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the size of the blockchain itself is the same for everybody. You can find graphs that show this size, for example [Blockchain Size](https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size).

All the other files you mentioned are databases and indexes that your specific client uses to find blocks in the blockchain, or to keep track of transactions or unspent outputs. The sizes of these files are client-specific.