# What is the format of the databases that are used in the core bitcoin client?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/what-is-the-database-for) tells what each of the files in the bitcoin directory are, but it doesn't explain the structure of the databases used. What is the table structure (columns, data type, etc) for each of the tables that the bitcoin client maintains?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair