# Are all blocks stored in one file or is every block stored in an individual file?

Tags: full-node, storage

I couldn't find an answer to that. So, are blocks stored in one or multiple files and in which file format?

Comment: _Are blocks stored in one file_ `No` _Is every block stored in an individual file_ `No` So every blk*.dat file has lot of blocks. Pieter Wuille has explained few related things in this answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/11108/ and this is just for Bitcoin Core. Other implementations can do this in different ways.

Comment: @Prayank Thanks, that's what I needed.