# Should I stop bitcoind when backing up chainstate/ and blocks/ directories?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, synchronization, utxo-set

This is how one might back up their Bitcoin Core data directories in order to save time on syncing in the future:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

local_d=/root/btc_db

rsync -av --delete chainstate "$local_d"
rsync -av --delete blocks "$local_d"
```

Sometimes backups to a remote location take quite a long time, and so there may a lag of many
block in between `rsync -av --delete chainstate "$local_d"` and `rsync -av --delete blocks "$local_d"`. Will Bitcoin Core [sync seamlessly](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/what-is-the-database-for/) when being fed `chainststate/` directory backup that corresponds to a different block height
than `blocks/` directory?